# I received the reputation cap hat before hitting the reputation cap

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-limit, winter-bash-2017

Yes, I have another two upvotes to go on Stack Overflow before hitting the limit.

My receiving this hat early is somewhat akin to my giving my daughter a Christmas present a day or two early. And that is ill-disciplined indeed.

It's a bit harder to implement than `if (delta_rep >= 200){`, but I know you guys are up to it. You're the best!

Comment: Hat might be given just for 200 rep, not hitting actual rep cap. The "hit rep cap to get the hat" is just a guess (as this is a secret hat), and might be wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well it was a nice gift anyway.

Comment: Not a bug. The same criteria apply for the repcap related badges: if you get to 200 in a day you earn it.

Answer (score 5):

You got 200 daily reputation about 20 minutes ago: (10 minutes before asking this question)

> [image: reputation history showing getting over 200 daily rep today]

So most likely this means the hat is awarded for simply having 200 rep a day, no matter how.

Comment: congratulations